# how to retrieve the whole data-file (ajax?) with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, database

http://newmap.australia.com/?locale=en-gb#

When I click on "Cities" on the left, then - any city.. for example Adelaide - it opens a short description of the city with dynamically embedded hyperlinks under "Find Out More" text and under "View Highlights" button (in the bottom of the section). All HTML content dynamically changes for each city section respectively.

All the data generates dynamically from probably some ajax accessed file/database.

How to get all these data with the hyperlinks at once ?? (instead of browsing through the whole site and scraping manually all the links for each city)

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Chrome if you open up your dev console and go to network tab you will be able to see all of the network calls the website is making.

As an example link to the list of cities:

http://newmap.australia.com/services/tnla/markerData/1/en-gb

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks mate. That's what I was after, just needed your indication. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "All the data generates dynamically" and it won't be a quick task.

A better approach will be to get the direct urls and take the entire page - then parse it for the releavant data.

- Main page for a city :
  http://www.australia.com/en-gb/places/adelaide.html
- "48 hours.." for a city :
  http://www.australia.com/en-gb/news/2015/november/48-hours-in-adelaide.html
- etc..

This way you will get the entire content and it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear for me

I guess you want to return data in json Format that contain hyperlink
in order to do that you have to make the json file properly server side 
and return it to client and place it in html page

you need something like this

```
 var cityCollection = [
                           city  {
                                 id = 1 ,
                                 name= Adelaide ,
                                 hyperlink = '<a href='1'>Adelaide </a>';
                                 },
                           city  {
                                 id = 2 ,
                                 name= sydney ,
                                 hyperlink = '<a href='1'>sydney</a>';
                                 },
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
                         ]
```